# Wpf - MVVM and Service in separate assemblies or folder

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, dll

I found many tutorial. In each View / ViewModel / Model and Service use folder. But, can I separate them in assemblies ?

For example:

**Core**

- ViewCore.dll (reference ViewModel)
- ViewModelCore.dll (reference Model & Service)
- ServiceCore.dll

**Module A**

- ViewModuleA.dll (reference ViewCore)
- ViewModelModuleA (reference ViewModelCore)
- ModelModuleA.dll
- ServiceModuleA.dll (reference ModelModuleA + ServiceCore)

**Other**

- Startup.exe (reference all dll + init service etc.)

What is the best way in C# / WPF ? Separate in different folder or assemblies ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just put them in separate projects.

Example:

Add a Class library project named: ViewModuleA, will result in ViewModuleA.dll

then you just reference the class library project, to the startup project, and import namespaces where needed.

Comment: thanks but what is the best way ? use separate folder (for each or some part) or assemblies for each part ?

Comment: I would have done that. For example if you want to take the advantage of dynamic module loading.

Comment: Generally,  The the main application shouldn't be aware of its modules. For example: If you have a sales application. You could add a Customer module, and dynamically load it based on what user is logged in.  The sales application should not need to know if the customers module is there or not. The customer module will contain its own hookups to the services it needs. Therefore we will achieve loose coupling between the sales application and the customer module.